# Geo nodes + rigid bodies not working

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, geometry-nodes

I was wondering if it would be possible to use the generated geometry from geo nodes as a rigid body **without** actually needing to apply the modifier.

I made a quick test where I have two rigid bodies, one ball(the active one), and a plane, with a geo node that generates a cube(the passive one), and the issue is that it seems that the geometry used to calculated the collision is just just the surface of the original plane:

[image]

Applying the geo node modifier works, but I would like not to do it the idea was to animate that cube/s inside the geo node modifier. I added the realize instance node just in case, but still doesn't work.thanks!

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could animate a parent object and have the child a rigid body... for this to work I think you need to use [vertex parenting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#vertex-parent), start with a 3 verts circle mesh and parent you rigid body to it in edit mode with mesh selected. Then just set the rigid body to animated...

Here's a [quick test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhgidlxjg474v2j/RBGN1.blend?dl=1) with some movement, but rotating your mesh works too, no sense here because it's a sphere..! sorry I have no time to try something more interesting.

I read that physics and simulations will be node based too, maybe you can integrate things if that happens.

Comment: just to clarify, you animate a single triangle in geometry nodes and your collision mesh is a different object, parented to those 3 vertices... so you can easily move and rotate the collision object but not change it's shape from geometry nodes